# mobilefirst ios hybrid app failed to connect to production server

Tags: ios, https, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

Im building an app that is already working in android, but when i tried to connect the same app in my iphone environment (ios 9.1) cant connect to my server

here is some of my configuration:

```
<iphone bundleId="com.xxxxxx" securityTest="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </iphone>
```

and the logs from my xcode:

```
2015-11-26 10:05:52.100 AppName[353:79399] [INFO] [AppName.core.main] wlCommonInit: Antes connect...
2015-11-26 10:05:52.102 AppName[353:79391] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
2015-11-26 10:05:52.105 AppName[353:78667] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.AppName
2015-11-26 10:05:52.121 AppName[353:78667] THREAD WARNING: ['UserAuth'] took '16.052979' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-11-26 10:05:52.124 AppName[353:79391] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
2015-11-26 10:05:52.129 AppName[353:79399] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/AppName/iphone/init]
2015-11-26 10:05:52.133 AppName[353:79393] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:38 :: Request url is https://DomainName:443/ProjectName/apps/services/api/AppName/iphone/init
2015-11-26 10:05:52.147 AppName[353:79393] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:183 :: Starting the request with URL https://DomainName:443/ProjectName/apps/services/api/AppName/iphone/init
2015-11-26 10:05:52.283 AppName[353:78863] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-11-26 10:05:52.284 AppName[353:78863] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2015-11-26 10:05:52.287 AppName[353:78667] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:215 :: Request Failed
2015-11-26 10:05:52.289 AppName[353:78667] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:216 :: Response Status Code : 0
2015-11-26 10:05:52.293 AppName[353:78667] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:217 :: Response Error : An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
2015-11-26 10:05:52.302 AppName[353:78667] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] -[NotificationEx loadingStop:] in NotificationEx.m:150 :: Loading stop
2015-11-26 10:05:52.342 AppName[353:78667] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '36.349121' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-11-26 10:05:52.444 AppName[353:79391] [ERROR] [NONE] [/apps/services/api/AppName/iphone/init] Host is not responsive.
2015-11-26 10:05:52.446 AppName[353:79399] [INFO] [AppName.core.main] wlCommonInit: connectFailure...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 9 requires use of Application Transport Security(ATS) for connection. Refer to the following blogs for more details and resolution of the issue:

a) [IBM MFP support for iOS 9](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/)

b) [Enable ATS for iOS 9 in IBM MFP](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/)

c) [ATS and BitCode](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a key to your **info.plist** -nsallowarbitrary
 connections to yes. This is new in **ios 9**